# Subtract result from 2 queries in JPA

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am having two tables namely Room & Allotment. Room has occupancy. And in Allotment I am storing person who is occupying room. Now I want to find out how much occupancy is available in each room.

**Entities**

```
@Table(name = "ALLOTMENT")
public class RoomAllotment {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ALLOT_NO")
    private Integer allotNo;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="RM_CD", referencedColumnName = "RM_CD")
    private RoomMaster roomCode;
   
    //some more columns
}

@Table(name = "ROOMS")
public class RoomMaster {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "RM_CD")
    private Integer roomCode;
    
    @Column(name = "ROOM_NO")
    @NotNull(message = "Room number is required")
    @Size(max=20, message = "Maximum 20 characters only")
    private String roomNo;
    
    @Column(name = "OCCUPANCY")
    @Range(min=1, max=10, message = "Occupancy can be minimum 1 or maximum 10 only")
    private Integer occupancy;

    //some more columns
}
```

In Database I have following values.

```
Room Table

RM_CD | ROOM_NO | OCCUPANCY |
-----------------------------
    1 |   A-401 |         5 |
    2 |   A-402 |         4 |

Allotment Table

ALLOT_NO | RM_CD |   OCCUPANT  |
--------------------------------
       1 |     1 |  Alex Warne |
       2 |     1 | Mike Parker |
```

Now I want all rooms with current occupancy.
Room 1 -> 5 - (two persons are living in room 1) = 3
Room 2 -> 4 - (No one living in room 2 yet) = 4

How can I write query for this. I have written one query but it gives me error.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT r.roomCode, "+
                "(r.occupancy- "+
                "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RoomAllotment ra WHERE ra.roomCode.roomCode=r.roomCode) "+
                ") occupancy"+
                "FROM RoomMaster r "+
                "ORDER BY r.roomCode")
Page<RoomDetails> findAllVacantRooms(Pageable pageable);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: occupancy near line 1, column 168 [SELECT r.roomCode, (r.occupancy- (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM com.datanet.model.osm.RoomAllotment ra WHERE ra.roomCode.roomCode=r.roomCode) )occupancy FROM com.datanet.model.osm.RoomMaster r ORDER BY r.roomCode]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `left outer join` and `group by` as follows:

```
SELECT R.roomCode, R.occupancy - COUNT(A.allotNo) AS occupancy 
  FROM ROOM R LEFT JOIN ALLOTMENT   A
    ON R.roomCode= A.roomCode
 GROUP BY R.roomCode, R.occupancy
```